# Installing Delphi 2005 TChart

Tags: delphi, installation, components, teechart, delphi-2005

I'm running the 2005 version of delphi, which is all we are allowed to use for our school projects (so I can't update to a more recent version of delphi)

What I'm trying to do is install the TChart component into my delphi so that I can add the component to my VCL Form however can't seem to find the download link for the source code to install it via a package inside of delphi.

Could you possibly help me get TChart installed onto my delphi 2005 version? If its even possible..

Thanks

Comment: Delphi comes with TChart

Comment: Delphi 2005 does not include the source code. I'm sure Steema would be happy to sell you a license. If TeeChart is a requirement for your course, but you don't already have it, then you should ask your instructor how to set up your environment.

Comment: Assuming you're using RAD Studio, search through the 'Tool Palette' on the bottom right of the screen. TChart should be there somewhere, though I can't remember which heading it's under. It's not under the 'Standard' list.

Answer (score 1):

As the previous comments indicate, TeeChart Standard should be included in Delphi 2005 installation, as with all RAD Studio versions.
If you want to use this version but you can't find the TChart component in the palette, search for the dcltee*.bpl in the bin folder in the IDE installation and try to install it through the Components list in the IDE.

If you want to use a different version (a Pro version or a SourceCode version), please contact the sales department at sales@steema.com. Note Steema Software offers a 50% discount for Academic & Non-profit Organizations: http://www.steema.com/licensing/subscription